# Why is not the RegExp version working when the /patt/ version works? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a working reg exp:

```
  var re = /([^\wåäö]*?)([\wåäö]+)([^\wåäö&]?|$)|.+/ig;
```

When I replace it with this one it does not work any more:

```
  var re = new RegExp("([^\wåäö]*?)([\wåäö]+)([^\wåäö&]?|$)|.+", "ig");
```

Should not these two be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape the `\` using `\\`. When you type, for instance, `\w` inside a regular expression literal (`/\w/`), it follows the regular expression syntax (which allow `w` after a `\`). When you do the same thing inside a string, it follows the string syntax, which does not allow it. So, you shoud instead write `"\\w"` to achieve the same effect (in other words, the RegExp's `source` will be `\w`).

Answer (score 2):

`\` is an escape character in regex as well as in a string.  You need to double up your `\`s in the 2nd version.

Comment: Thanks James. Your answer is short and right to the point (but I could only set one of the answers as the "accepted" answer).